# check arbitrary list index existence in python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

See the following code,

```
if 'COMPONENTS' in prod.keys() and len(prod['COMPONENTS'])>0 and len(prod['COMPONENTS'][0])>1 and len(prod['COMPONENTS'][0][1])>0 and len(prod['COMPONENTS'][0][1][0])>2:
  names = prod['COMPONENTS'][0][1][0][2]

  if type(names) == list and len(names)>0 and type(names[0]) == str:
    #names is proper. Now fetch prices
    if len(prod['COMPONENTS'][0])>3:
      lnames = len(names)
      prices = [prod['COMPONENTS'][0][3][i][2][1][0][1] for i in range(0, lanmes)]
```

See how I am using `prod['COMPONENTS'][0][1][0][2]` and `prod['COMPONENTS'][0][3][i][2][1][0][1]`. `prod` is a very deep nested list. I want to check if element exists in such index.

I dind't find any way. Currently I am using a long condition on if statement. See above how long they are. They are terrible.

So is there any way to check if `prod` can satisfy `['COMPONENTS'][0][3][i][2][1][0][1]` indexes?

Comment: What devilish data structure mess is this? :-)

Comment: Heh I have converted some [catalogue file](http://www.dansononline.co.uk/acatalog/A000183.cat) by `ast` and got this structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is just to do it and catch the error:

```
try:
    names = prod['COMPONENTS'][0][1][0][2]
except LookupError:
    print "It failed"
    # Do whatever you need to do in case of failure
```

LookupError will catch missing indices in a list or missing keys in a dictionary.

Needless to say, though, you've already found the real problem: you're using an unwieldy and awkward data structure.  It might be possible to bypass the problem by storing your data in a different way.

Comment: I am trying to parse [this file](http://www.dansononline.co.uk/acatalog/A000183.cat) with python. I converted it with to python data structure and ran `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @GenghisKhan: Then I guess you're stuck with it ;-).  I don't envy you the task of dealing with that, it looks pretty ugly.